# How do I create virtual ALSA device from which I can record everything that is played?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

Should not depend on PulseAudio.

Like veth for network, of v4l2loopback for video, it should create virtual audiocard from which I can record everything that is played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load the kernel module: `modprobe snd-aloop`
2. Use `plughw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0` device for recording
3. Use `plughw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1` device for playing (or vice versa).